# What are the options for saving data in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'd like to serialize a bunch of data and save it to a file, then be able to load it (naturally) and play it back with a feature I have written.  (Sorry if my terminology is off, I am a novice with this sort of thing.)  What is the best way to do this with iOS?  From looking at documentation here:

[Standard Application Behaviors Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/StandardBehaviors/StandardBehaviors.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH4-SW12)

I've gathered that I should use 
[NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Miscellaneous/Foundation_Functions/Reference/reference.html%23//apple_ref/c/func/NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains) for finding the appropriate storage directory root (Documents?) and then use [NSData](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSData_Class/Reference/Reference.html%23//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSData/writeToFile:options:error:) to store these data buffers I create and write them to file.  Am I spot on with that or have I got it wrong?  Any other sage advice?

Answer (score 18):

You can use plist.
It is very easy to save list of string or other data without using core data.
See [Property List Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/PropertyLists/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000048i)

For example, this code will save an object (rootObj) which can be an array or a dictionary:

```
NSString *error;
NSString *rootPath = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *plistPath = [rootPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"yourFile.plist"];
NSData *plistData = [NSPropertyListSerialization dataFromPropertyList:rootObj
                                                               format:NSPropertyListXMLFormat_v1_0
                                                     errorDescription:&error];
if(plistData) {
  [plistData writeToFile:plistPath atomically:YES];
}
else {
  NSLog(@"Error : %@",error);
  [error release];
}
```

There is some limitation on supported class (see the guide)

Comment: dataFromPropertyList is deprecated.

Comment: Error: ARC forbids explicit message send of 'release'

Answer (score 14):

It depends on the data you are writing. If you mostly want to serialize objects, see the [NSCoding](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Protocols/NSCoding_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intf/NSCoding) protocol. If you have some simple data structure that’s not a class, you can store that into a `NSDictionary` and save it into a plist. And if you have a big chunk of data (like thousands of floats or something like that), you might want to save that using `NSData` as you already hinted. In any case be sure to read the [Archives and Serializations Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/Archiving/Archiving.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000047i) so that you don’t reinvent the wheel.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, pretty right direction. You need to implement something, that is called NSCoding protocol on your object to be able to archive & unarchive it into NSData. See the example:
[Saving files on iOS using NSFileManager](http://www.raywenderlich.com/1914/how-to-save-your-app-data-with-nscoding-and-nsfilemanager)