# Help with logic on NSUserDefaults

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uitableview, nsuserdefaults

Hey guys i need some help with logic in my app. I have an app that is a checklist that lets u add or delete cells. I want to store the cells in NSUserDefaults so that way, when i open the checklist page up again, the checklist will be just as it was when the page was closed! Any help would be appreciated! Thanks a lot everybody!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`NSUserDefaults` is there to store things that look more like settings. For your task you'd better use Core Data or store data yourself in a separate file.

Here is the official [tutorial](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/DataManagement/Conceptual/iPhoneCoreData01/Introduction/Introduction.html) which is pretty good. It can (actually, intended to) be integrated with table views. There are lots of [tutorials](http://www.softwareinteractions.com/blog/2010/2/7/uitableview-and-core-data.html) out there.

You should also check this SO [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4075056/saving-data-in-ios).