# Can I store files in an iPhone's file system?

Tags: ios, xcode

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [saving data in iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4075056/saving-data-in-ios)

Do we have a provision profile to select or save a file in directories in an iPhone using `NSPathUtilities.h`?

Comment: Well you might find your answer on here. Not sure. http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Working_with_Files_in_Objective-C

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Within your app sandboxed environment yes.